# How can I enable JETTY JNDI lookup (jetty-plus) when running jettyEclipseRun

Tags: gradle, jetty-9

The title pretty much says it all.

Context: I'm trying to use https://github.com/Khoulaiz/gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin to run some integration tests but I need to prepare database state before running test cases. When lookup failed both for jdbc/"name" and java:/comp/env/jdbc/"name" I discovered I had to enable *plus* features. I'm not running Jetty from the command line, so I cannot provide the OPTIONS argument.

Comment: have you got some progress yet?